# How do we evaluate this limit?

Tags: limits, infinity

$$
A_N(x) = \lim_{N\to \infty}(\sin(x)/x)^N
$$

The solution to this problem is given as,

$$
A_N(x) = \exp( -Nx^2/6).
$$

The problem is solved through

1. Taylor series expansion for $\sin(x)$.
2. And the famous limit

$$
\lim_{N\to \infty}(1+(x/N))^N = \exp(x).
$$

I'm not able to figure out the disappearance of some of the higher degree terms. How exactly is this limit calculated . An insight would be great.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{N\to \infty}(1+(x/N)+ H.O.T.)^N = exp(x)$

where H.O.T. are Higher Order Terms. So you can put the remainder of Taylor series there.

BTW your formula for $A_N(x)$ contains an error. If it's a limit as $N \to \infty$, how can the answer depend on $N$?

Comment: It can depend on N . Even though it depends on N it goes to 0 for large values of N which means that it has a definite limit of 0 and hence it is bounded also. But the limit still exists without the addition of H.O.T that you have mentioned.